# Mercurial/Git flow - When are new heads created?

Tags: mercurial

We have a course where we study Mercurial. I have a question regarding Mercurial but I believe Git acts the exact same way here.

To answer this question I used the Mercurial Workbench and followed the graph after each command.

This is the question:
For the following sequence of mercurial operations, explain which line(s)
cause the number of heads to change in any of the referenced repositories (say which
repository is affected, and why). Assume the main repository initially has a single
head, with some existing data:

(I have bolded what I think are lines where new heads are headed)

1. /home/user> hg clone http://remoteserver/mainrepository clone1
2. /home/user> hg clone http://remoteserver/mainrepository clone2
3. /home/user> cd clone1
4. /home/user/clone1> hg tag initial
5. /home/user/clone1> echo one > a.txt # Create a new file “a.txt” containing “one”
6. /home/user/clone1> echo two > b.txt # Create a new file “b.txt” containing “two”
7. /home/user/clone1> hg add a.txt
8. /home/user/clone1> hg commit -m ”Added a file”
9. /home/user/clone1> hg tag file-one
10. /home/user/clone1> hg push -f ../clone2
11. /home/user/clone1> cd ../clone2
12. /home/user/clone2> echo three > c.txt # Create a new file “c.txt” containing
    “three”
13. /home/user/clone2> hg add c.txt
14. **/home/user/clone2> hg commit -m ”Added another file”**
15. **/home/user/clone2> hg push -f ../clone1**
16. /home/user/clone2> cd ../clone1
17. /home/user/clone1> hg up initial
18. /home/user/clone1> hg add b.txt
19. **/home/user/clone1> hg commit -m ”Added yet another file”**
20. /home/user/clone1> hg up file-one
21. **/home/user/clone1> hg push -f ../clone2**

I came to this conclusion:

- on row 14, a new head is created on clone2
- on row 15, a new head is created on clone1
- on row 19, a new head is created on clone1
- on row 21, a new head is created on clone2

We end up with 3 heads in clone1 and 3 heads in clone2.

My question is:

1. Is this correct?
2. Can you explain to me what happens at each step a new row is added? 
   I tried to come up with my own reasons but I need an expert opinion on this.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (1): yes, that's correct.  For (2), <s>I'm not sure what you're asking ("at each step a new row is added"—what does the word *row* mean here?).</s> [**Edit per comments**] let's look at steps 14, 15, 19, and 21 with respect to previous steps.

At step 14, you run `hg commit -m "Added another file"`.  The *current* commit is not an existing tip commit, because at step 12 you moved into the "clone2" directory / clone, whose *current commit* is unchanged from the time you made the clone (at step 2).  That is, if the current commit was numeric-ID `0` and hash-ID `a1234567....` at step 2, that is still the current commit, even though step 10 added more commits to that repository.  (The current branch is probably `default`, although this is less important since both clone1 and clone2 are on the same branch and the commits added to clone1 are now present in clone2, on that same branch.  The key item is that the current *commit* in clone2 is not the head of the current branch in clone2, thanks to the pushed-in commits.)

In a more typical situation, such as that at step 7, you'd be on a head commit (a commit with no children) when you make the new commit.  Making the new commit creates that new commit with the current commit as its parent, so that the commit that *was* a head (had no children) is no longer a head (has a child); and the new commit itself, being new, has no children and is therefore a head.  The count of heads is therefore adjusted both -1 (loss of previous head) and +1 (gain of new head via new commit).

But the new commit you make at step 14 has a not-a-head-anymore commit as its parent.  Its "headness" was erased earlier by the `git push` at step 10, when it acquired a child commit.  Now it has *two* children, which leaves it not-a-head; and the new child commit, being a new commit, has *no* children, making it a head.  The head count is thus adjusted +1 with no offsetting -1.

At step 15, you run `hg push -f ../clone1`.  This puts the new commit you just made at step 14 into clone1.  Since the new commit you made is a head, clone1 gains a new head.

Step 19 is similar, but we're back in clone1 (due to step 16).  The *current* commit is not an existing head, thanks to step 17 (`hg up initial` which uses the tag to find the commit to switch-to).  You make a new commit, which is automatically a new head; but the commit to which you add this new commit as a new child is not itself a head, so the head count goes up one.  Step 21 simply pushes this new commit into clone2: it's new to clone2, so it is a new head, but it does not transform any existing head into a non-head.

#### You haven't gotten here yet, but...

Note that when you use `hg branch <newbranch>` and then `hg commit`, you create a new child for whatever commit was current at the time, but that new child is *in a different branch*.  The new commit, which becomes the current commit, is the new head of the new (now existing) branch, and the fact that it's a child of the commit that used to be current is irrelevant, since "head-ness" is determined by whether there are child commits *in the same branch*.

#### More generally (pre-edit text continues below)

> ... I believe Git acts the exact same way here

It does in terms of *commits*, but not in terms of *heads*.

Mercurial defines *head* as *any commit with no outgoing arcs into (child commits in) the same branch.*  Mercurial's *branches* are very different from Git's, and Git more or less defines a head as "any commit that has a branch name pointing directly to it" (though Git calls these *tip* commits, and refers to the branch name itself as a "head").

Git's branches have no permanence: they exist only because the branch name itself exists, and the branch name exists only as long as you don't tell Git to delete it.  As soon as you delete the name, the branch ceases to exist.  The *commits* stick around until there are no more references to them, at which point the garbage collector (once it runs) discards them.  Some references are squirreled away in *reflogs* and there's a separate reflog for each branch (deleted when the branch is deleted) plus one for the special name `HEAD` (*never* deleted), so even though the branch's reflog references vanish, the `HEAD` reflog references tend to keep deleted-branch commits alive for a while.

If those (in-Git) commits are reachable from some *other* branch, they continue to stick around because of that.  Meanwhile, every commit in Git is, in general, reachable from *N* branches simultaneously (*N* being any nonnegative integer, and usually *N* ≥ 1).  We say that those commits are *contained within* those branches.  By contrast, every commit in Mercurial is on *exactly one* branch, with its branch having been chosen at commit-time, and it never changes.

In other words, we can say that **in Mercurial, a *branch's* existence depends on *the commits that are on the branch;* but in Git, a *commit's* existence depends on *the (branch and other) names that contain that commit.***  Any name will do, including tag names—Git has a bigger namespace here than Mercurial, since its tags are stored externally (which makes them unversioned, with all that this implies).

To make this work in Mercurial, "head-ness" is an automatic property of a commit, and to make this work in Git, "head-ness" (or branch-tip-ness) is managed *manually* instead.  To make it *mostly*-automatic, `git commit` will automatically update the current branch (whose name is stored in `HEAD`) to point to the new commit just made.

Both VCSes add new commits the same way: they take whatever is in the proposed commit—stored in Git's *index*, or in Mercurial's work-state as shown by `hg summary`—and package that into a real commit, whose parent is the current commit.  In Mercurial, having made that commit, we're done: it's automatically a head as it has no children.  In Git, having made the new commit, our final task is to write the commit's ID into the current branch name, so that the branch name now points to the new tip commit.

Comment: I see. When I meant "row" I want command #14, #15 etc.
If I could get an explanation on exactly why each new head was created at the commands I have bolded, I'd appreciate it